# Firestore Timestamp toDate() returns wrong UTC date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following dates stored in my **Firestore Emulator v9.16.0**:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, when my mouse hover on the `EndDate`, it shows the correct UTC Date, i.e. `2021-08-13T11:09:58.000Z`, but when I issue the following code, it returns the wrong UTC date (`2021-08-13T09:09:58.000Z`):

**In my localhost server Node.js:**

```
let maintConfigRef = db.collection("Configurations").doc("Maintenance");
let maintConfigDoc = await maintConfigRef.get();

if (maintConfigDoc.exists) {
     let maintConfigData = maintConfigDoc.data();
     let endDate = maintConfigData.EndDate.toDate().toJSON(); // Returns 2021-08-13T09:09:58.000Z
     console.log(endDate); // Output "2021-08-13T09:09:58.000Z"
};
```

Which means it should be `...T11:09` (as shown in the tooltip) instead of `...T09:09`. Anyone knows what's wrong with it and what else should I do to get it right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried `toUTCString()`?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Firestore timestamp does not have `toUTCString()`, but I tried using `.toDate().toUTCString()`, even worse: `Fri, 13 Aug 2021 09:09:58 GMT`, which should be `Fri, 13 Aug 2021 19:09:58 GMT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it was a bug, but after installing `firebase-tools 9.16.5`, the problem disappeared:

`npm install -g firebase-tools`